# How to convert pdf file to svg file using itextsharp in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, svg

I have project in that project I have to convert `PDF` file to `SVG` file.

Note: PDF contains images.

Please suggest me how to convert PDF to SVG file

Comment: why you people put negetive marks anthing i asked wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to follow the steps..

1. Convert the PDF to images..
2. then use each image and convert it so SVG using Canvas(that is possible way)..
3. Use final result as per requirement..

Note: Post some of your work for more clarity

Comment: actually i am new in that i am not getting anything in that if u help it greatfull plse give one sample example.

Comment: @woohoo Please see the question and requirement, the answer was accepted by the owner.
Thank you for showing your knowledge here about SVG. But answer is not about what you want. Its about PDF to SVG without specifying Vectors. If you have separate requirement it should be new question.